# How can I make my json query wait for phone's location?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, geolocation

Here I am trying to send a json query with latitude and longitude but these values are going as NaN even though I call the ShowMyLocationOnTheMap which retrieves phone location first. How can I make the showMyLocation method finish first and then call json query. Can you help me out?

```
public partial class ClosestBusStops : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    WebClient webClient;
    public ClosestBusStops()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ShowMyLocationOnTheMap(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
        string jsonQuery= "www.blabla.com?lat="+App.lat+"&lng="+App.lng;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(jsonQuery));
    }

    private async void ShowMyLocationOnTheMap(GeoPositionAccuracy accuracy)
    {
        Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
        GeoCoordinate myGeoCoordinate = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);

        App.lat = myGeoCoordinate.Latitude;
        App.lng = myGeoCoordinate.Longitude;

        this.pushPin(this.mapWithMyLocation, myGeoCoordinate);

    }
}
```

UPDATED

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {

            await ShowMyLocationOnTheMap(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
}

private async Task ShowMyLocationOnTheMap(GeoPositionAccuracy accuracy)
        {
            Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
            Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
            Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;
            GeoCoordinate myGeoCoordinate = CoordinateConverter.ConvertGeocoordinate(myGeocoordinate);

            App.lat = myGeoCoordinate.Latitude;
            App.lng = myGeoCoordinate.Longitude;

            this.pushPin(this.mapWithMyLocation, myGeoCoordinate);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShowMyLocationOnTheMap` is an async method, so if you want to wait for completion of this method, you need to use the `await` keyword, like this:

```
await ShowMyLocationOnTheMap(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
```

Since you cannot use await in constructor, you need to move this to somewhere else, like `OnNavigatedTo` method or `Loaded` event handler.

Also return type of `ShowMyLocationOnTheMap` should be `Task` instead of `void`.

UPDATE:

```
    public ClosestBusStops()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async Task ShowMyLocationOnTheMap(GeoPositionAccuracy accuracy)
    {
        Geolocator myGeolocator = new Geolocator();
        Geoposition myGeoposition = await myGeolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
        Geocoordinate myGeocoordinate = myGeoposition.Coordinate;

        App.lat = myGeoCoordinate.Latitude;
        App.lng = myGeoCoordinate.Longitude;

        this.pushPin(this.mapWithMyLocation, myGeoCoordinate);
    }

    protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        await ShowMyLocationOnTheMap(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
        webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
        string jsonQuery= "www.blabla.com?lat="+App.lat+"&lng="+App.lng;
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(jsonQuery));
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did as you say but gives this error: Error The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: I have got one less problem thanks to you, Abhishek. =)